# How to encrypt the data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating an application with sensitive data's. I need to store the data to the `mongodb`, but if anyone reads the data. It should be in encrypted format. If i read it from my application, it should give the original data, it should show encrypted data's to any support team users if they read it from backend.

I want to achieve this without using any encryption logic from Application. Is there any way mongo encrypts/decrypts data automatically?

Comment: You need to encrypt it before you store the data. If you are working with any sensitive data PLEASE make sure you are following all best practices. 
1) Do I really need to store this information? 2) does the information need 1 way or 2 way encryption (passwords should never use 2 way; only hashes; other data should be encrypted with strong open source encryption and the key to read them stored equally secure

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers Steven. Is there any support provided from MongoDB to support encryption. I can see Wired Tiger engine provides some methods to encrypt the data. How does it do?

Comment: Start here and then keep on reading: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption/

Comment: @vasantharajan note that storage-level encryption is an Enterprise feature, and requires a MongoDB Enterprise Advanced subscription: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/. It is not available in the Community Edition.